# Plotly Dash: How to open external link from callback?

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm working on Dash for data visualisation using Python.
Using the html.A component is not a solution for me. Since the user himself has to click on the link. I need to do some calculations before opening an external link.
Can I somehow open an external link in a new tab using the callback code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. If you need to do your calculations in Python, then I would say probably do that in one callback, which triggers a second callback. Write the second one as a [clientside callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) and include [something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) to open a link using JS.